# Counting the total number of characters in a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count the total number of characters in a table.

I know how to do it for one column:

```
select sum(leng)
from (
    select len(column) as leng
    from table
) as Total
```

But how do I do this for every column in a table?

One way I have thought of is

```
select sum(len(col1) + len(col2) + len(3) + ...) as TotalChracters
from Table
```

But I need to do this for over 500 tables, and each table has a lot of columns. I was hoping for a general code that works for one table which I can easily loop over in Python by just changing the table name on each loop.

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: In Python you can query the `sys.columns` table to get all of the columns and tables  (or all of the columns for a list of tables) then from that have python write your tedious SQL, execute it, and do something with the results. That's the only way you can dynamically reference columns and tables (by writing the sql through a script and executing).

Comment: Does all your tables has only string columns? Only one method I can think of it is using DynamicSQL

Comment: As @JNevill suggested, you can use `max_length` in `sys.columns` for text fields, and `precision` for numeric columns.

Comment: Why do you need this? How should columns that arent strings, such as datetime or uniqueidentifier be treated?

Comment: What use could this possibly serve? Does it really matter how many characters are stored in the database? Storage space I understand but who cares if there 1.8 million characters or 7.8 billion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some code that does not run the query but it is almost the same as it will the desired code for any number of tables and columns in your DB.
Also, includes the ISNULL, so, if the table is empty it will show 0:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT T.Name as Table_Name, 
    C.Name as Column_Name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Name ORDER BY T.Name, C.Name) AS RowASC,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Name ORDER BY T.Name, C.Name DESC) AS RowDESC
FROM sysobjects T 
INNER JOIN syscolumns C
  ON T.ID = C.ID
WHERE T.XType = 'U'
)
SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN RowASC = 1 THEN 'SELECT ISNULL(SUM(' ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN RowASC = 1 THEN 'LEN('+Column_Name+')' ELSE '+LEN('+Column_Name+')' END +
    CASE WHEN RowDESC = 1 THEN '), 0) AS [TotalCharacters on Table: '+Table_Name+']
    FROM '+Table_Name +' UNION ' ELSE '' END AS Query
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Table_Name, Column_Name;
```

Just need to copy the column at the Right (Query) and paste in a new query window.

Comment: Great solution! Is there a way to concatenate the Query so that the full query is in one cell?

Comment: Great !!! I just have modified the query to show a UNION from all results. Just elimminate the latest UNION, run the query and paste into MS-Excel where you can summarize.

Comment: @Fabio, I'm glad you found your answer. Please take a moment to mark this as your accepted answer by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer. It lets other users know the question has an answer, and rewards the user who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.

Comment: I don't understand why it has been unmarked as the right response... any failure?